# Android music pauses when using headphones

Tags: music-player, google-play-music

This started happening a few days ago but my phone stopped to play music (pausing) on headphones when I:

1. Screen off
2. Notification menu is pulled down
3. Opening all applications on the default stock launcher

Music plays only if the music app is in foreground or if I went to the launcher and not selected anything.

I am using custom rom but it stopped working on it after using it for over a month. I tried to update the rom to a newer one but it still doesn't work.

Music plays fine when not using headphones and just using the speakers.

Phone: Note2
ROM: temasek cm11 (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2596887)

Kernel: Devil's kernel (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2239453)

App: Apollo and Google music (same thing), pretty much every music application on Android

Comment: I had the same issue on my phone. Seems to be related to the launcher. This seems to be a KK Note 2 related issue.

Comment: I solved mine with a new faster sdcard.

Answer (score 1):

Are your headphones defective or have a weak spot? You can try a couple of things, such as testing this on another Android device.

It could potentially be the ROM and its ability to detect headphones properly while doing different things (Multi-tasking in a sort of sense).

What you can do is go into Settings and turned Motion off. Sometimes it can sense movement and such and it'll pause accordingly. I'll look into this more but into l your next response, this is what I have to say.

**Update**

It is probably an Android 4.2.2 issue. You can downgrade, wait for an upgrade or perhaps install the 4.3 KitKat ROM.

Other options are trying newer/older versions of the Google Play Music software.

Comment: So after I played around with it, apparently it's 4.4.2 that has issues. I tried many variants of 4.4.2 on Android. I switched back to 4.3.2 and it was fine, I guess i will have to downgrade. :\

Comment: Now that you mention it, I most certainly agree. I remember having the same Google Play Music issues. You just reminded me. And perhaps you can wait for an  upgrade? I know there are 4.3 KitKat ROMS  it you're interested.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you use GEL? If so, it's because of it listening to "Ok Google". Turn off "Hotword detection" in GEL Voice settings and you'll be fine.

Comment: Well it fails to work in any other app and the notification menu and I was using stock 4.4.2 android, I don't think that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be related to a conflict between voice search from lock screen and music being played from locked screen. For me the following worked on Android 4.4.4 (tried and tested on OmniRom and CyanogenMod):

> ```
> Go to Google Now | Settings | Voice | Select "Ok Google Detection"
> Uncheck "From lock screen"
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I got this problem and my Google play assistance open itself and music pause/skip on any kind of music player which I using. Samsung music/Spotify. And now whenever I use another headphone there is no problem. So before doing anything make sure your headphone or your phone socket is fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar issue with the Galaxy A10e. Only with me it's not when I'm multi tasking but when I have my phone in my pocket. The only thing that helps is messing with my headphone cord as if it was my headphones and no it's not my headphones because it does the same thing with my other headphones. It still does it after I turned of the motion setting.

It's really frustrating because I rather listen to my music than come across potential social situations on my way to work.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling Google hotword detection fixes this issue in 4.4.4.